# Pickling a dictionary that contains pygame.Surface objects

Tags: pygame, pickle, display, surface

So I have a dictionary called `Images` and it stores `pygame.Surface` objects. Instead of having to build this entire dictionary every time I run the code, I would just like to read it in from a file.

This is the code that I am trying to use to pickle and unpickle the dictionary:

```
with open('Images.pkl', 'wb') as output:
    pickle.dump(Images, output, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

with open('Images.pkl', 'rb') as input:
    Images = pickle.load(input)
```

Later on, I use this code:

```
class Survivor:
    def __init__(self):
        self.body_image=Images['Characters/Survivor/handgun/idle0']
        self.body_rect=self.body_image.get_rect()
```

which gives me:

> File "ZombieSurvival.py", line 1320, in **init**
>       self.body_rect=self.body_image.get_rect(center=self.vector)
>    pygame.error: display Surface quit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to pickle the dictionary by first using pygame's `pygame.image.tostring()` function to convert every `pygame.Surface` in the dictionary `Images`, to a string, using `pygame.image.tostring()`. Then I pickled `Images`. Whenever I want to use `Images`, I unpickle it and convert every string in it back go a `pygame.Surface` using `pygame.image.fromstring()`.

However, `pygame.image.fromstring()` requires us to tell it the size of the `pygame.Surface` that it is about to convert, so I saved the sizes of each `pygame.Surface` before I used the `pyame.image.tostring()` function.

On every occasion where I was about to call `pygame.image.tostring()` on a `pygame.Surface`, I first stored the `pygame.Surface`'s key (it's location in `Images`) and its size in an instance of a `class` with fields `key` and `size`. I stored every instance of this class in a list called `list_of_image_sizes`, and pickled the list.

Now, when you use the `pygame.image.fromstring()` function, you can call it as such:

```
for data in list_of_image_sizes:
    Images[data.key]=pygame.image.fromstring(Image[data.key], data.size, 'RGBA')   
    #RGBA is my particular argument, you can change it as you wish
```

Answer (score 2):

`pygame.Surface` objects are actually a wrapper around a [SDL_Surface](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Surface), which is a C structure handled by the SDL library. This structure must be created with a call to the `SDL_CreateRGBSurface()` function of the SDL library.
This is probably done somewhere in `pygame.Surface.__init__()`.

But unpickling an instance does not initialize it in a normal way. As the [pickle documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/pickle.html#pickling-class-instances) says:

> When a class instance is unpickled, its **init**() method is usually
>   not invoked

So the C structure is never initialized and everything goes wrong.

Comment: So is there not a way to call the `SDL_CreateRGBSurface()` function during the unpickling?